# Is there a software that adds a history to file dialogs on Windows?

Tags: windows

Is there a software that extends the Windows file dialogs so they have a history of recently accessed directories? For Max OS X there is [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/index.html), but for Windows I didn't find anything.

If you know such a software, what is your experience with it:

- Can you recommend it?
- How stable is it?
- Does it work with all file dialogs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Access Folders](http://www.shelltoys.com/access_folders/index.html)** adds support for favorites folders to the standard File Open/Save dialog.

[image]

It won't work with all file dialogs, as some programs have their own File Open/Save dialog to add extra features.

[**FileBox Extender**](http://www.hyperionics.com/files/index.asp) is another one that's free but I've never used it. The remark about non-standard file dialogs is still valid though:

> FileBox enhances Windows by adding
>   several advanced functions to the
>   standard Open File and Save File
>   dialog boxes. (Note that if a program
>   uses its own "private" dialog boxes
>   for these functions, you won't see our
>   FileBox buttons, sorry.)